# Any() Throw Exception when object is null, how return null instead?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following query in linq,

```
List<SolicitudSeccion> solicitudesSeccionEliminar = solicitudBD.SolicitudSeccion?.Where(bd => 
!solicitudEdit.SolicitudSeccion.Any(ed => bd.IdSolicitudSeccion == ed.IdSolicitudSeccion))?.ToList();
```

I have solved when "solicitudBD.SolicitudSeccion" is null so that .Where() does not error, putting a "?.Where()", the case is that solicitudEdit.SolicitudSeccion is null .Any() throw exception and I can't put a "?.Any()" to avoid the exception

Any ideas?

Comment: What you mean you **can't put `?.Any()`**? Why?

Comment: Is `solicitudBD` null or `SolicitudSeccion`?

Comment: Or even `bd` at some point?

Comment: If **one item** in `solicitudBD.SolicitudSeccion` is `null`, then `Any` will break because `bd.IdSolicitudSeccion` will be `null.IdSolicitudSeccion`

Comment: Give us a minimum verifiable example please

Answer (score 0):

Handle the null object with ?.Any(..) == false

```
List<SolicitudSeccion> solicitudesSeccionEliminar = solicitudBD
  .SolicitudSeccion
  ?.Where(bd => 
    solicitudEdit
    .SolicitudSeccion
    ?.Any(ed => bd.IdSolicitudSeccion == ed.IdSolicitudSeccion) == false
  )?.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think this will solve the problem? (if `solicitudEdit.SolicitudSeccion` is `null`, then your code will return an empty list, where one could expect every item of `solicitudBD.SolicitudSeccion` instead)

Comment: Because solicitudEdit.SolicitudSeccion is null and solicitudEdit.SolicitudSeccion.Any() throws a null reference exception. Handling that with solicitudEdit.SolicitudSeccion?.Any() == false will fix the problem.

Comment: But OP said he couldn't fix his problem with `?.Any`

Comment: I think what you mean to say, is that using the *null coalesce operator* causes the result to be `nullable<bool>` and as such cant be used by the *logical negation operator* `!` because of the *nullable* type, however you can lift it by explicitly specifying `==`

Comment: `bool?` without value does not equal to `true` or `false`

Comment: Exactly `bool? b = null;` b == true and b == false  both evaluate to false